# Regex номер больше 255

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Кто сможет написать Regex с условием number > 255

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9]|000)$
```

Или инвертировать это где number < 255

Comment: Наверняка найдутся умельцы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так, покрывая числа в диапазонах 256-259, 260-299, 300-999, больше 1000:

```
^(25[6-9]|2[6-9]\d|[3-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d{3,})$
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Слжешь также для 16383 сделать?

Comment: Так принцип тот же, пишешь по разрядам, какие числа допускаются.

Comment: Вообще, проще не играться с регулярками, а распарсить число и сравнить его значение: `Integer.parseInt(str) > 16383`

Comment: Я делаю ковертов с mysqlanywhere to mysql и мне нужно заменить только те поля которые мне нужно. Файл может быть и 1GB, вот почему мне нужен Regex

Например: 
char(256) -> text(256)
char(254) -> char(254)

Comment: (1638[4-9]|1639[0-9]|16[4-9][0-9]{2}|1[7-9][0-9]{3}|[2-9][0-9]{4}|[1-9]\d{5,}) 

number > 16383

Comment: Да, вроде бы нормально